# Cannot execute appengine-mapreduce using DatastoreInput with query filters

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

when I try to use datastore Query with a filter like this :

`Query billQuery = new Query("Bill");
billQuery.setFilter(new Query.FilterPredicate("payedOn", Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, new Date()));`

and trying to run :
`new MapReduceSpecification.Builder, List>>>(new DatastoreInput(billQuery, mapShardCount),
            new SimpleCounter("BillID"), new CountReducer(), new InMemoryOutput>())
            .setKeyMarshaller(Marshallers.getStringMarshaller())
            .setValueMarshaller(Marshallers.getLongMarshaller())
            .setJobName("MapReduceTest count")
            .setNumReducers(reduceShardCount)
            .build();`

I get this exception :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payedOn: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity is not a supported property type.`

where 'paidOn' is property with Date value in a datastore entity.

This ewxample is very similar to that in the [example] :

so I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea, it is a standard datastore query.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in this line: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/inputs/DatastoreShardStrategy.java#L386
Until fixed, you could avoid the issue by supplying both bounds (upper and lower) or patch it yourself by replacing item.get(0) with item.get(0).getProperty(propertyName)

Comment: The fix for it was submitted to gitHub (but not yet pushed to maven).